# Why is this perl substitution not working?

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

```
$test2 = "<id><![CDATA[cyber_monday_deal]]></id>\n";

$test2 =~ s/<id><![CDATA[cyber_monday_deal]]><\/id>/<id><![CDATA[cyber monday deal 3]]><\/id>/m;

print $test2
```

I get the old test2, and not the substituted one.

Does any quote work to escape the whole string to be substituted.?

Comment: What do you think `s/</id>/</id>/m;` is doing? You're substituting something with itself, you forgot to escape the `/`s, and the original string doesn't match the regex anyway.

Comment: @Dan, no, the two sides aren't identical

Comment: they were, when I wrote it for the first time..My bad..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[CDATA[cyber_monday_deal]]` is a character class.

Comment: close: `[CDATA[cyber_monday_deal]` is a character class

Answer (score 1):

Judging on your recent questions, your attempt to process XML with Regex is failing. You clearly do not even understand that square-brackets must be *escaped* in regexes. Thus the specification *shouldn't be*

```
/<![CDATA[cyber_monday_deal]]>.../
```

but

```
/<!\[CDATA\[...\]\]>.../
```

*Use a proper XML parsing module, please*. http://perl-xml.sourceforge.net/faq/

Answer (score 0):

You can use \Q to indicate a part of the regex where metacharacters such as [ should be considered as literal characters:

```
$test2 =~ s/\Q<id><![CDATA[cyber_monday_deal]]><\/id>/<id><![CDATA[cyber monday deal 3]]><\/id>/m;
```

The effect of \Q ends at \E or the end of the regex.  It doesn't make `$` or `@` literal, but does make any regex interpolated with them literal.